# A word or idiom for being offended for someone else

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

Is there a word or idiom to describe being offended for some one else?

For example, Person A makes an off-the-cuff remark that person B is 'trailer trash'.  Person B knows that person A means it as a joke and isn't offended. Person C then gets offended at the remark and jumps to person B's defence even though the remark had nothing to do with them. Person A and B often make these remarks to each other.

Comment: Would the word *vicarious* work for you?  It means to feel through the imagined experience of others.  However, it doesn't apply only to offense.

Comment: Note that it is possible and even reasonable to be offended *for yourself* by a person's use of language even if that language is not directed at you or disparaging of your demographic.

Comment: I'm assuming you want something mocking or disparaging? If so, I've heard various variants along the lines of "trying to be [X]'s knight in shining armour" but there isn't any particular answer-worthy set form I can think of. Example usage: "Erm, thanks but I don't need a knight in shining armour here, I can take a joke"

Comment: Person C was **triggered** even though the remark had nothing to do with them.

Comment: I have a distinct memory that this question has already been asked here, somewhere.

Comment: Reminds me of the barber shop scene in *Gran Torino* when Tao watches Walt and the barber exchange insults. Tao is not offended but stunned: "WALT:
          Afternoon, Martin, you dumb
          Italian prick.

          BARBER:
          Walt, you cheap asshole, I should
          have known you'd come in, I was
          having such a pleasant day.

          WALT:
          Why, did you jew some blind man
          out of a few bucks, give him the
          wrong change?
          *Walt and the Barber shake hands warmly. Tao is wide-
          eyed.*

Comment: I suppose   "SJW"  is right out.

Comment: good lord please don't use "triggered"

Comment: @sgroves my apologies for triggering you :)

Comment: I'd note that most of the terms proposed here are implicitly stating that pointing out that a term is disparaging is inherently unreasonable to do. 

It is perfectly possible to observe that a term being used - "trailer trash" as the provided example - is generally considered to be insulting or judgmental without being angry or upset about it.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon, true, but what you're describing is *not* 'being offended'.

Comment: @Benjol, right - I was slightly unclear. I have noted a tendency to assume offense was taken when a solecism is mentioned when in fact the motivation was only dispassionate editorial observation. "That term is kind of mean." "Oh, and when did you become the enforcer of standards?" and so on.

Answer (score 36):

I would suggest **vicariously offended**.

[Vicarious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vicarious):

> performed, exercised, received, or suffered in place of another

I've found a few published uses of the phrase:

[Use 1:](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1YUQCAAAQBAJ)

> ... making their living by being vicariously offended ...

[Use 2:](http://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2013/jun/08/rugby-player-brian-moore-much-know)

> There's a tendency in this country for people to be vicariously offended

Comment: +1 But, when we give examples on this site, we usually include quoted text and often a link to the source. Also your first link is broken.

Comment: @bib The link worked for me but I've changed it to the index page of the book. Hopefully it works now but it won't take you directly to the quote. I included the excepts in either case.

Comment: To riff off of this excellent answer, what about _sympathetically indignant_?

Answer (score 15):

A term I have seen used more recently is **Professionally Offended** or **Professionally Outraged**.

This is used to describe someone who takes offense at something on behalf of the supposedly offended party, usually on Twitter.

> Phillip Schofield has described Twitter as "the land of the professionally outraged".

[DigitalSpy](http://www.digitalspy.com/showbiz/news/a554802/phillip-schofield-twitter-is-land-of-the-professionally-outraged/)

Comment: It's worth noting that this is a negative, potentially derogatory term.

Comment: Not a problem, since they're always offended by everything anyway. ;)

Comment: I'd say this better describes someone who is frequently in the state in question.  It wouldn't be appropriate to describe a one off instance of offence on behalf of another as being "professionally offended".

Answer (score 7):

The idiom, *take something personally*, may fit in this scenario. Definition:

> to interpret a remark or action as directed against oneself and be upset or offended by it, even if that was not the speaker's intention.

Example:

> "I *took it personally* when he yelled at the class."

([The Oxford Pocket Dictionary of Current English](http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O999-personally.html))

Comment: That is the opposite of what he's asking - taking something personally means exactly that you're offended on your own behalf, hence the "personal". This is explicitly *not* taking something personally.

Comment: @neminem -- To *take something personally* means to be offended by a remark that may not have been aimed at you. This fits the OP's scenario. Returning to the OP's original example, it would make sense for Person C to respond, "*I take classist insults personally.*"

Comment: No, to "take something personally" means to take something as directed to you personally and potentially be offended by it. It explicitly does not mean to take something as directed to someone else, which would be non-personally.

Comment: I think it could be interpreted both ways.

Comment: I've never heard of "taking something non-personally". Kyle's interpretation is closer to the truth in my view (native speaker).

Comment: My understanding is this means that the insult or remark was aimed at a general group, of which the offendee is a member, but they react as if it had been directed specifically at them.

Answer (score 5):

I think **took umbrage** would be a nice fit.

Example:

> Person C took **umbrage** at person B's remark about person A.

Comment: *Umbrage* is synonymous with *offense*, so this does not answer the question.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is still a valid idiom.

Comment: It's not specific to being offended on someone else's behalf. You can take umbrage at an insult to yourself, or you can take umbrage at a remark about someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Beside the question of real understanding from B (was it a joke or not from A...), we have to answer your first request : **Empathy** which means a comprehension & imaginatively entering or projecting into another person's feelingsh.

Answer (score 4):

"**on behalf of**" is a good fit here.

> "in the interest of" -
>   [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behalf)

Example:

> I’ve noticed the phenomenon of someone getting personally offended on behalf of someone else, who, in fact, has not been personally offended.
>   [Use in an article](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/geneveith/2011/11/being-personally-offended-for-someone-else/)

Answer (score 2):

Though not commonly used, this type of offense can be said to be a **secondhand offense** as explained in this [article](http://hannahscupboard.com/wake-nov04-3.html).

Answer (score 1):

acting as the PC (political correctness) Police

of course this is meant as a slight to the third party - sort of a "mind your own business" response

Comment: This is too narrow—one can be offended by remarks about someone else even if they have nothing to do with political correctness.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that Person C is being **overprotective**.

> having a tendency to protect someone, especially a child, excessively.

Answer (score 0):

The idiom “[more loyal than the king](http://www.siasat.pk/forum/showthread.php?52050-Pakistan%92s-Liberal-Extremists-More-Loyal-Than-The-King)” was used by an author as a subtitle in a 2010 opinion piece criticizing a fellow Pakistani columnist for expressing misplaced concern on behalf of the United States over the possibility that leaks from within ISI (Pakistan’s powerful spy service)  had revealed  the name and identity of the then CIA station chief in Pakistan, in spite of the fact that the United States itself had not voiced such concerns through official channels.

In the first paragraph, the author of the piece states the idiom’s meaning as follows:

> The idiom ‘More loyal than the king’ means someone who unnecessarily
>   behaves more concerned about matters that concern someone else and
>   ought not to have been of such concern to him. Generally it is spoken
>   about sycophants or those subservient to the concerned, for their
>   undue zeal and interest in matters owed directly to someone else.

(from ‘Pakistan’s Liberal Extremists: :More Loyal Than The King’ on ‘siasat[dot]pk)

Although the second sentence about how the idiom is generally targeted  at unduly zealous sycophants would probably not apply in your context  as presented, the idiom as defined in the first sentence would describe “Person C” in your scenario, with the United States representing your  “Person B” and “sections of the US media” playing the role of your “Person A.”

Please note that variations of this idiom include “[more **royal/ist** than the king](https://books.google.com/books?id=fPPbvPHHL4UC&pg=PA135&lpg=PA135&dq=%22more+royalist+than+the+king%22&source=bl&ots=0EEzK8E4Ea&sig=nhvEekJUZZ7_FnnBuKKcoezwMds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDwKLwrrbLAhUC7mMKHZ3-BFg4ChDoAQhSMAk#v=onepage&q=%22more%20royalist%20than%20the%20king%22&f=false)” and “[more papal/Catholic than the Pope](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/more_Catholic_than_the_Pope),”

the latter being defined by Wikipedia (as an extension of its literal meanings) as:

> Adhering more stringently to any norm (the norm of what is considered
>   offensive, in your case) more strictly than is required by the
>   arbiters of the norm (Person B, in your case);

with the former (as paraphrased from its use in ‘When the King Took Flight’ by Timothy TACKETT, via ‘Google Books’) meaning:
 someone who “abides no compromise [when it comes to offensive language, in your case]” even when/if the king himself [Person B, in your case] does/would abide such compromises.